# Why doesn't Strict Origin work? (at least in FireFox)

Tags: security, firefox, multiple-domains

I visit `mozilla.com` and I have checked my `about:config` is set to turn `Strict Origin` on (enabled: true) and yet when I display the browser console it shows my browser is going to `gravatar.com`, `google-analytics.com`, `casalemedia.com`, and a whole host of others.  It certainly isn't just accessing other pages under the domain of `mozilla.com`.  How is this protection being defeated?

Comment: The only "strict origin" item I can find in Firefox's `about:config` is [`security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy), which, as the name indicates, applies only to file URIs. What config item are you referring to?

Comment: security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy;true   and the file examples I'm referring to are - GET https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/d0d90148e08e3b64ccf75c46f31442c5 [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 1949ms]
GET https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/7185c716eeef78738b7f2cee6c10830f [HTTP/1.1 302 Found 1953ms]
GET https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/7ed44ab074fb193d09935b6a512c3381 [HTTP/1.1 302 Found 787ms]
GET https://www.google-analytics.com/r/collect

Comment: That config item, as its name implies, only applies to **file URIs**. Mozilla.com is not a file URI.

Comment: What do you think is being got with the GETs?  --- Files.   See wikipedia for this text - The user visiting the malicious site would expect that the site he or she is visiting has no access to the banking session cookie. While it is true that the JavaScript has no direct access to the banking session cookie, it could still send and receive requests to the banking site with the banking site's session cookie. Because the script can essentially do the same as the user would do, even CSRF protections by the banking site would not be effective.

Comment: File URIs mean URLs like `file:///Users/ceejayoz/Desktop/Screen%20Shot%202017-03-09%20at%205.20.12%20PM.png`. Per the documentation at http://kb.mozillazine.org/Security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy, "When local HTML files (**e.g., those located on your hard drive**) are loaded into the browser, the scripts and links within have restrictions on what they can see and do. Those restrictions are determined by the same-origin policy for local files, which this preference controls."

Comment: The vulnerability you describe with banking sites is why banking sites and other high-security sites **should not include third-party scripts on their pages**. It has nothing to do with this config setting, though.

Comment: @ceejayoz - Oh, okay.  Thanks for your help.  Any way I can stop my browser from letting a website waste my time by going to other (advertizer's) sites?

Comment: There are a wide variety of adblocking and privacy extensions for Firefox.

Comment: @ceejayoz - if you look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy you see in the green and pink table that the failures are due to different hosts on an HTTP protocol, not FILE://.  Why is not mozilla.com failing, as in this table, to access other websites??

Comment: The same-origin policy applies to **scripts** making things like AJAX requests cross-domain. It has zero impact on things like embedding an image in a website. It would, for example, prevent StackOverflow.com from making an AJAX call to capitalone.com's API and getting your bank balance.